# MongoEngine: 'ListField' object has no attribute 'in_bulk'

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

Given the following setup (reduced):

```
class Parent(db.Document):
    _id = db.ObjectIdField(required=True, default=lambda: ObjectId(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.StringField(required=False)
    test = db.MapField(db.EmbeddedDocumentField('Child'), required=False)
    
class Child(db.EmbeddedDocument):
    _id = db.ObjectIdField(required=True, default=lambda: ObjectId(), primary_key=True)
    ref = db.ReferenceField('Parent')
    
parent = Parent.objects(_id=x).first()
return jsonify(parent.test)
```

I get the following error: `AttributeError: 'ListField' object has no attribute 'in_bulk'`

```
  File "/home/me/testSetup/test.py", line 310, in get
    return jsonify(parent.test)
  File "/home/me/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mongoengine/base/fields.py", line 329, in __get__
    value = _dereference(value, max_depth=1, instance=instance, name=self.name)
  File "/home/me/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mongoengine/dereference.py", line 97, in __call__
    self.object_map = self._fetch_objects(doc_type=doc_type)
  File "/home/me/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mongoengine/dereference.py", line 174, in _fetch_objects
    references = collection.objects.in_bulk(refs)
AttributeError: 'ListField' object has no attribute 'in_bulk'
```

I'm not quite sure why this is happening. I did not use a ListField at all. I can access `name` and `_id` and this setup worked with other classes before. `return jsonify(parent)` does also work and it includes the `test` field with all its values. Does someone have an idea?

**EDIT:** I am silly and removed/censored the part that is causing the error from the reduced example. The field `test` was actually called `objects`. Renaming it resolved the error.

Answer (score 1):

Using raw mongoengine (no flask-mongoengine), from a fresh database, and from a simple terminal, the following code is working

```
from mongoengine import *
from bson import ObjectId

connect("testdb")

class Parent(Document):
    _id = ObjectIdField(required=True, default=lambda: ObjectId(), primary_key=True)
    name = StringField(required=False)
    test = MapField(EmbeddedDocumentField('Child'), required=False)
    
class Child(EmbeddedDocument):
    _id = ObjectIdField(required=True, default=lambda: ObjectId(), primary_key=True)
    ref = ReferenceField('Parent')

p = Parent(name='aa', test={}).save()
p2 = Parent(name='bb', test={'test': Child(ref=p), 'test2': Child(ref=p)}).save()

print(Parent.objects(_id=p.id).first().test)

print(Parent.objects(_id=p2.id).first().test)
```

I'd recommend you to start from there, add more complex code until you can pinpoint what causes it to break.

side note, since ObjectId is a callable, you don't need to wrap it in a lambda and can simply use `default=ObjectId` in your field definition, thus `ObjectIdField(required=True, default=ObjectId, primary_key=True)`